# Constructions of the verb Promise

Tags: grammar

I have an easy question about the usage of the verb promise.

Is it correct to use it with this contruction?

**Promise to [somebody] + to [base form]**

Is it commonly used?

---

Examples:

1) He promised to me to keep my opinion secret.

2) I promised to John to help him out.

Or I should always use the standard construction with the "that-clause".

1) He promised (me) that he would keep my opinion secret.

2) I promised (John) that I would help him out.

Comment: The normal indicative verb *promise* does not take the preposition *to*. So you do not "promise to someone", you "promise someone".  And in 1. you do not need the pronoun "me", as the person promised is already clear from the use of *my*. So sentences should read: "He promised to keep my opinion secret" and "I promised John to help him out".

Comment: I've always thought that we can't say "I promised John to help him out", but we need a relative clause after the object (John). Am I wrong?

Comment: Shakespeare thought you were wrong: he wrote in *Twelfth Night:* *his highness hath promised me to do it*. [Google Ngrams](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=promised+him+to%2Cpromised+him+that&year_start=1700&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=10&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cpromised%20him%20to%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cpromised%20him%20that%3B%2Cc0) shows that *promised him to* was dominant in the 18th century, but the construction is slowly losing out to *promised him that*. So the construction might be old-fashioned or maybe archaic, but it's not slang.

Comment: @TestPat12 Yes, on second thoughts, I think I'd say 'I promised John  (that) I'd help him out'. But in Britain I do think the infinitive version is not altogether dead.

Comment: If you *want* to use a *to [someone]* construction, you can change the verb to the phrase *give a/one's promise*, so *He **gave a promise to me** that he would keep my secret* or *I **gave my promise to John** that I would help him out* and so forth. The connotations might shift a little bit –
 *giving a promise* sounds to my ear both a little more solemn and perhaps a little more...childish? than just *promising* – but it's a subtle enough difference that in most cases you could probably swap them out for one another.